# group by year and boolean column postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, group-by

I have the following table

```
id   |  created_on   | is_a   | is_b    | is_c
----------------------------------------------
1    |  01-02-1999   | True   |False    |False
2    |  23-05-1999   | False  |True     |False
3    |  25-08-2000   | False  |True     |False
4    |  30-07-2000   | False  |False    |True
5    |  05-09-2001   | False  |False    |True
6    |  05-09-2001   | False  |True     |False
7    |  05-09-2001   | True   |False    |False
8    |  05-09-2001   | True   |False    |False
```

In the table resulting the query, I would like to group by year of creation, and then be able to compare how many records were created in each year for `is_a` and `is_b`. I want to completely ignore from the count `is_c`.

```
count_a | count_b  | by_creation_year
-----------------------------------------------
1       |1         | 1999
0       |1         | 2000
2       |1         | 2001
```

I tried the following query:

```
select count(is_a = True) a, 
       count(is_b = True) b,
       date_trunc('year', created_on)
from cp_all
where is_c = False  -- this removes the records where is_c is True
group by date_trunc('year', created_on)
order by date_trunc('year', created_on) asc;
```

But I get a table where the count of a and b is exactly the same.

Comment: You're very close. Just change `count` to `sum` in your select because your conditional doesn't return `null` which `count` would have ignored in aggregation. Instead it returns 2  `non null` values -- 0 and 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I like filter, this is simpler to type:

```
select sum(is_a::int) as a, 
       sum(is_b::int) as b,
       date_trunc('year', created_on)
from cp_all
where is_c = False  -- this removes the records where is_c is True
group by date_trunc('year', created_on)
order by date_trunc('year', created_on) asc;
```

Answer (score 3):

Your `count()` argument evaluates to `true` or `false` which each gets counted as `1` regardless.

You want to use `filter`

```
select count(*) filter (where is_a) a, 
       count(*) filter (where is_b) b,
       date_trunc('year', created_on)
  from cp_all
 where is_c = False  -- this removes the records where is_c is True
 group by date_trunc('year', created_on)
 order by date_trunc('year', created_on) asc;
```

Doing it this way you will not need the `where` clause.

Answer (score 1):

That's because `count` does not take boolean expressions it simply uses the expression and evaluates to check whether it is `null` or `not null` to add to the counter. So in this case you should use `sum` with `case`

```
select sum(case when is_a then 1 else 0 end) a, 
       sum(case when is_b then 1 else 0 end) b,
       date_trunc('year', created_on)
from cp_all
where is_c = False  -- this removes the records where is_c is True
group by date_trunc('year', created_on)
order by date_trunc('year', created_on) asc;
```